# Mapbox GL - Can we add animation while filtering layers

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I would like to do some animation while filters are being applied on layers. For example, I have 2 layers with circles drawn of different radius on some geo points. While I switch from one layer to other layer by setting filters using setFilter(), I want the transition on circle opacity for a smooth transition.

Please assist

Answer (score 2):

You can use `circle-opacity` to enable/disable layers.
Set the opacity to 1 for active layers and to 0 for hidden layers.

I made a jsfiddle to illustrate this: https://jsfiddle.net/kmandov/kqey8y72/1/

Change the option from the select box to switch between the layers on the map.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what if I have set some filters on the layer and want to manipulate on it.

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle, so I can help there! Regards

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox doesn't support this feature yet. see this [issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/2273)